# Voting eachtime sets to 1 How to solve this?

Tags: php, mysql, vote

Each time i vote up or down it just sets an 1. 
But i want that votes_up=votes_up+1 inkrements eachtime i vote up.

this is php code

```
 public function voteUp($id)
  {
    $this->initDB();

    $q="update twitter.tweets set vote_up=vote_up+1 where id=$id";
    $this->db->query($q);
  }
```

the result is

Down Votes:1

Up Votes:1

Total Votes:18

How can i solve that Down Votes and Up Votes are inkremented?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You aren't setting $id or something else is going wrong. This SQL looks fine. .

Comment: id is correct set so with id is everything ok if the id were wrong i couldnt set the vote up to set on for that id

Comment: Did you try running that SQL in the console? Because I bet it works just fine.

Comment: sorry that was a template problem so your answer is correct pls edit your answer so that i can vote up and accept your answer

Answer (score 0):

I assume there is a `voteDown()` function of basically the same structure. Perhaps that is also being called unnecessarily.

Have you looked at the database structure? Perhaps the data type is wrong for the `vote_up` column. I would think you would want the type to be `int unsigned not null default 0`.